# CSS circular image at any size

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a circular image with CSS.

When my image is 200px x 300px, it's not a perfect circle:

```css
.circular {
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
  -moz-border-radius: 150px;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1ZCs.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="circular"></div>
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gfn2ots9/) as well.

Is there a way to make a perfect circle when the width and height are different sizes? If I set this to 300 x 300 it's a perfect circle, but I need it to be in a perfect circle when the image is 200 x 300.

Comment: I don't get the idea why you need different sizes if you need a circle shape?

Comment: Is there away to make a circle without adjusting the width or height in the jsfiddle

Comment: The best you can achieve is something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/sy48k3y5/3/

Comment: i think it is not possible as circle has equal radius allover. but i think you should try to calculate which value is greater i.e. width or height. Whichever is greater use that dimension/2 as your radius.Simple

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't make it a circle if the values aren't square, its that simple. You can, however, make the wrapper square and hide the remains of the circle if you nest your image in it. It would be something like this:

```css
.circular {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.circular img {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="circular">
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150" />
</div>
```

I usually wrap all the lines between and including `position:` and `transform:`in a separate CSS definition with the `:nth-child(n)`selector so the centering only works on browser that support nth-child, but thats just fine-tuning.

Comment: +1 - excuse the edit. This is a good method and the Stack Snippet makes it easy to see.

Comment: @misterManSam Thats fine (at first I wasn't sure what changed). I'll edit it to add some prefixes as that doesnt work and I'm using safari (and if it doesnt work for me then it a bit embarrassing :p)

Comment: what is we dont know the exact pixels of width, like if i am using width as 10% then your code will notwork

Comment: @aravindreddy True, none if this works if you use percentages - that's understandable since percentages in height rarely match them in width. If you want to do that, you might want to define the wrapper as say `width: 10vw`, `height: 10vw`. If you cannot use those values, your last resort is calculating them in JS.

Answer (score 2):

There is one way, with [`transform: scale`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#scale), to wrestle it into shape. I don't know why you would need it... here it is anyway. The scale values would obviously need to change with the width / height.

Another problem is a background image would be distorted using this method.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #F00;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(.76, .5)
}
```

```html
<div><div>
```

Comment: Yeah this is just overcomplicated, cant see why you'd use this either as  you now have to calculate two things!

Comment: +1 Nice approach the problem here is you will need to know the proportions in order to set the transform values.

Comment: @Danko Yes, and the accepted solution is rather simple. I wasn't thinking outside the... circle.

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve it by changing the HTML structure a bit.

```
<div class="circular">
   <img src="img/desktop.jpg">
</div>

.circular { /* need to give parent container equal width and height*/
    margin: auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.circular img{
    width:100%;
}
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/prakashup/2sb6srjp/

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what size the image is in your example because it is a bg image. The parts that don't fit will just not be rendered. If you need a 300px by 300px circle, then just leave the hight and width at 300.
You can use `background-size:cover;` to make the image stretch to fit but preserve aspect ratio.

[See here.](http://jsfiddle.net/rally25rs/sy48k3y5/6/)

```css
.circular {
margin: auto;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
background: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSJVLN-vcVHCOOLWmvihkfex1OFW0ZLVhQ7JQfcc4EH4YoJLTn68x8EpDls) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="circular"></div>
<br/><br/>
<div>Original image: <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSJVLN-vcVHCOOLWmvihkfex1OFW0ZLVhQ7JQfcc4EH4YoJLTn68x8EpDls" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, to achieve a circle using the border-radius property, your width and height values *must* be the same.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Understood and apologies

Answer (score 0):

you can use `border-radius:100%`. This can be used to create circle or ellipse shape. Also can be used anytime border-radius to be directly co-related to elements width

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by making height and width value same and defining border-radius as 50%.  here is the code..

```
.circular {
margin: auto;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
background: url(http://cdn.bavotasan.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/desktop.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it with pseudo elements

```css
.circular {
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
}
.circular:before {
  content: url('http://cdn.bavotasan.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/desktop.jpg');
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="circular"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I work in `scss` instead of `css`, the following is what worked for me to have a circular container that has max-diameter of 150 pixels, an with the image fully contained within this circular container so that the final image will not be collapsed into some oval shape instead:

```
.circular-container {
    max-width: 150px;
    max-height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: auto;

    img {
        max-width: 150px;
        width: auto;
        max-height: 150px;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 10px solid transparent;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        object-fit: scale-down;
        }
    }
```

The equivalent in `css` would be:

```
.circular-container {
    max-width: 150px;
    max-height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: auto;

.circular-container img {
    max-width: 150px;
    width: auto;
    max-height: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    object-fit: scale-down;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
    max-width: 150px;
    width: auto;
    max-height: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    object-fit: scale-down;
    }
```

> Blockquote

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).