# Make perfect round circle on image

Tags: css

I have an image that have width:3507px and height:4960px. When I style it with the border-radius 50%, the image receives an oval shape, but I want to receive an circled image. I tried object-fit:cover and object-position:center but they don't resolve the situation. How can I receive an circled image? I am using Chrome.

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26759594/css-circular-image-at-any-size/26760010

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `div` element (instead of the `img` element) for which you define identical width and height (i.e. a square) plus `border-radius: 50%`, and apply that image as a background-image in there, with `background-size: cover` and `background-position: center`.